# Can't wrap my head around array_filter()

Tags: php, html, arrays, array-filter

```
<html>
<style>
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
div {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 520px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

table{
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 520px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>

<div>
<h1>Students By Major</h1>
<br>
<?PHP

$students = array(
            array('name' => 'Rex Solertan', 'hrs_attempted' => 23, 'gpa_points' => 28, 'major' => 'CIT'),
            array('name' => 'Rivka Alexander', 'hrs_attempted' => 41, 'gpa_points' => 103, 'major' => 'EET'),
            array('name' => 'Ned Ramos', 'hrs_attempted' => 28, 'gpa_points' => 52, 'major' => 'BUS'),
            array('name' => 'Zoe Martinez', 'hrs_attempted' => 30, 'gpa_points' => 93, 'major' => 'WEB'),
            array('name' => 'Carl McElan', 'hrs_attempted' => 54, 'gpa_points' => 100, 'major' => 'WEB'),
            array('name' => 'Bob Palla', 'hrs_attempted' => 21, 'gpa_points' => 36, 'major' => 'CIT'),
            array('name' => 'Tilda Downey', 'hrs_attempted' => 31, 'gpa_points' => 86, 'major' => 'CIT'),
            array('name' => 'Mary Proth', 'hrs_attempted' => 33, 'gpa_points' => 105, 'major' => 'CIT'),
            array('name' => 'Zelda Rowe', 'hrs_attempted' => 12, 'gpa_points' => 39, 'major' => 'BUS'),
            array('name' => 'Sue Mar', 'hrs_attempted' => 20, 'gpa_points' => 50, 'major' => 'BUS'),
            array('name' => 'Max Stone', 'hrs_attempted' => 42, 'gpa_points' => 80, 'major' => 'EET'));


//**** NEED TO FIGURE OUT FILTER TO DISPLAY ONLY STUDENTS WITH CERTAIN MAJOR FOR EACH SELECT ITEM BELOW ****

if (isset($_POST["business"])) {


}
if (isset($_POST["computer_information_technology"])) {


}

if (isset($_POST["electrical_engineering_technology"])) {


}

if (isset($_POST["web_site_design"])) {


}

//WORKING CODE TO DISPLAY ALL STUDENTS NAME, GPA AND MAJOR (PROGRAM WILL RUN AS EXPECTED BUT ONLY DISPLAY REQUESTED DATA FOR ENTIRE ARRAY NOT SPECIFIC MAJORS)

echo "<table border ='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'> \n";
    echo "<tr><td>Name</td><td>GPA</td><td>Major</td></tr>\n";

$length = count($students);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

        $points = $students[$i]['gpa_points'];
        $hours = $students[$i]['hrs_attempted'];
        $GPAz = ($points / $hours);
        $GPA = round($GPAz, 1);
        $Major = $students[$i]['major'];
        $Name = $students[$i]['name'];

        echo "<tr><td>$Name</td><td>$GPA</td><td>$Major</td></tr>";


}

?>
</html>
```

This is for a project and I'm not asking to just get the answer.  I have pretty much completed the project but I just need to create a filter to only display certain array elements (major) when the select item pertaining to the element is selected from my HTML form.

I have figured out how to display the requested data for the entire array and I have been researching the array_filter() function but I do not understand how to input the data into it.

I assume I can create the filter function and use the code I already created to display the array elements I want or will that have to be re-written as well?

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php is pretty well documented.  If you don't understand the anonymous functions, or closures, then do some research on that, but otherwise it's just a matter of having a function return true (to keep in the array) or false (to remove from the array).

Comment: A normal application is going to store data in a database, and you'd query against that database. It's much faster and easier to use a database query to get a filtered set of results than do what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're already iterating over the array I suggest a different approach for solving your problem using `in_array()` function and an additional variable `$filter`

First create an array `$filter` with the ***majors*** to be displayed.

```
$filter = array();

if (isset($_POST["business"])) {
    $filter[] = "BUS";
}
if (isset($_POST["computer_information_technology"])) {
    $filter[] = "CIT";
}

if (isset($_POST["electrical_engineering_technology"])) {
    $filter[] = "EET";
}

if (isset($_POST["web_site_design"])) {
    $filter[] = "WEB";
}
```

Then inside the `for` loop display the element only if `$Major` exists in the array `$filter`:

```
if( in_array( $Major, $filter ) ) {
    echo "<tr><td>$Name</td><td>$GPA</td><td>$Major</td></tr>";
}
```

---

Reference:

**[in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)**

Comment: Thank you very much, this was indeed a very simple solution that did exactly what I needed.  I also (painstakingly) found out I was incorrectly using isset() for select values.  I ended up changing them to if(isset($_POST["major"]) && $_POST["major"] == "BUS") for each one.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution:

```
// lookup array for majors
$major_lookup = [
    "business" => 'BUS',
    "computer_information_technology" => 'CIT',
    "electrical_engineering_technology" =>  'EET',
    "web_site_design" => 'WEB',
];
// your intial students array
$students = []; 

$major_filter = $_POST['major_filter'] ?: '';

// if `$major_filter` key presents in 
// `$major_lookup`, then filter by it's value:
if (isset($major_lookup[$major_filter])) {
    $major = $major_lookup[$major_filter];
    $students = array_filter(
        $students,
        function($v) use ($major) {
            return $v['major'] == $major;
        }
    );
}

// output $students as usual
```